# Where to put ajax scripts for forms (what controller) in mvc?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, symfony-1.4, coupling, cohesion

This is my situation:
I have a single view (lets call it view **V**) with a formform with multiple combo box for selecting some parameters.

I want to load the options of those combo box via AJAX calls dynamically (selecting one item on a combobox will load the other ones with data)

Each combobox makes an AJAX request to a different controller (which in turn call on different models to fetch the data) on the framework. Lets call those controllers **C1**, **C2**, **C3** and the models **M1**, **M2**, **M3**.

These AJAX scripts on **C1**, **C2** and **C3** are *very likely* to be used on other views on the future

But i have my doubts if this is the correct way to go. Where do i put those AJAX scripts? On each controller or a separate one (probably called FormAPI or something like that)

Putting one ajax script on each controller i am coupling V with **C1**, **C2** and **C3**, while making one controller for the three requests will only couple my view V with one controller. Also, from my point of view, such controller will be highly cohesive.

However, i am probably not keeping my code DRY because **C1**, **C2** and **C3** already have some logic to recieve requests of the type "get list of **M1**, **M2** and **M3**", which i could render as JSON and return it to the view **V**

What happens in the future if i have another view **V2** that needs requests to **C1**, **C2**, **C3**, ... **CN**? I think soon my code will be "spaghetti coupled"

What do you think?

Another question: Should i have logic on M1, M2, M3 to get arrays and lists of items?
For instance, if M1 has multiple instances of M2, is it correct to create a method M1->getM2asArray()

Comment: You can create a base action class (which extends `sfActions`) and put the common logic into it and C1, C2, C3 should extend this class. Maybe you should create only one common action to these Ajax updates and decide which model should be used based on a request parameter.

Comment: @1ed You mean i should make one action on a controller that recieves the request, and make a switch based on the parameters? That's similar to making a single controller which has all the actions. Also, where do i put such single action? I could make an interface to the actions that makes them provide a method, but that doesnt change the fact that i need to call C1, C2 and C3 explicitly (since there is a 1-1 relation with C1 to M1)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar case but it wasn’t combo-box it was with auto-completes,
All scripts would be the scripts folder, reference to the script file in the mvc views.

I have several autocompletes on my MVC, I added one controller named it `AutoCompleteController` (that return Json data) and added jQuery & my custom script on the Layout page so they can be used on all the pages (In my application 90% of the pages have the autocomplete)

Example of my autocomplete controller

```
namespace ADM.Ntrasal.Web.UI.Browser.Controllers
{
    public class AutoCompleteController : Controller
    {
         private readonly IRepositories Repositories;
         public AutoCompleteController()
        {  //Prefare to use Ioc but for simplicity
            this.Repositories = new Repositories();
        }
        //
        // GET: /AutoComplete/

        public ActionResult EmployeeNames(string term)
        {
            var count = 10;
            var UserProfileRepostery = this.Repositories.Create<UserProfile>();


            var result = UserProfileRepostery.GetAll().Where(x =>
                  x.Employee_Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))
              .Take(count).Select(x =>
                  new
                  {
                      label = x.Employee_Name,
                      id = x.UserID
                  });
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
}
```

I made one AutoCompleteViewModule

```
public class AutoCompleteViewModule
{
public AutoCompleteViewModule()
{
    //default values
    AutocompleteCount = 10;
    Type = AutoCompleteTypes.EmployeeNames;
}
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Field { get; set; }
public int AutocompleteCount { get; set; }
public AutoCompleteTypes Type { get; set; }
```

I added an editor template to manage the autocomplete output html

```
@model ADM.Ntrasal.UI.Web.Browser.Models.AutoCompleteViewModule
 <input type="text"  name="AutocompleteTextBox"
     data-target='@Model.Field'
     data-autocomplete="@Url.Action(@Model.Type.ToString(), 
     "AutoComplete", new { count =    @Model.AutocompleteCount })"
     value='@Model.Name' />
@Html.Hidden(@Model.Field)
```

If I don’t want to add the needed script for the autocomplete, I will put it in an optional section and reference the script whenever on any view I need an auto-complete.

I will use the below in my views:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=>@Model.AutocompleteField)
```

I blogged about this in detail,  I can put a link if you see it is helpful

For the second question, I will get the data in each Model as you suggested and call it in my autocomplete controller so it will provide the needed data for the autocomplete template (or partial view)

Comment: Which language is it o_O ? Not PHP for sure.

Comment: @j0k I's something in between ruby and c#

Comment: @Ali Taki Sure, i'd like to view your blogpost on detail. Its good to see someone else arrived to the same solution of having a single controller

Comment: @JavierIEH, here is my post about the subject, Im currently using it,[link](http://ata2931977.blogspot.com/2012/07/mvc-autocomplete-template.html)